# SELECT STATEMENT WITH SUBQUERY date - 30 days

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 20112 I need to select the ***row ID*** from the `dbo.table` where the date is 30 days older than the date of the last record (the last record does not have to be today's date!).

SO....

The child query to get the right date is as follows:

```
SELECT cast(max(table_time) - 30 as datetime) 
FROM dbo.table 
WHERE column_value = 105
```

This returns exactly one `[date]` value as string `'2014-02-03 ....'`

Next I use this child query as a sub-query for the parent `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT max(row_id) 
FROM dbo.table 
WHERE table_time = (SELECT cast(max(table_time) - 30 as datetime) 
                    FROM dbo.table 
                    WHERE column_value = 105)
```

...but this does not return the `row_id` I am looking for (it returns `NULL`). I tried to cast the date as follows but got the same NULL result

```
SELECT max(row_id) 
FROM dbo.table 
WHERE table_time = cast((SELECT cast(max(table_time) - 30 as datetime) 
                         FROM dbo.table 
                         WHERE column_value = 105) as datetime)
```

I suppose that if the child query returns a valid date value I should be able to use it in the parent select statement as a value I could compare/validate against.

Where I am wrong ?

Comment: What do you want to happen when no rows meet the condition?  `NULL` seems like a reasonable option, but you might have other ideas.

Comment: ..ahhh, you r right. Sorry, long day :) yes it has to return NULL in case -30 days puts it out of range of related records.

Comment: Please don't use shorthand date math like `datetime - 30` - see [here](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx) and [here](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx).

Comment: ... well written. Thanks for the :  Little-known fact: it also works with decimals :)

Answer (score 1):

---Use the 'cast' function in the 'where' clause as well

```
      SELECT max(row_id) FROM dbo.table 
      WHERE cast(table_time  as datetime)=       
      (SELECT cast(max(table_time) - 30 as datetime) 
       FROM dbo.table WHERE column_value = 105)
```

Comment: ...good suggestion I guess if I want to be double sure I am comparing two exactly the same data-types